# Reduce a HashMap to another HashMap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I start of with a string like this:

```
"train, Train, bike, BIKE, car...etc"
```

of travel types, and need to return a `HashMap<String, Integer>()`, such as this:

```
(train, 4), (car, 6), (bike, 2)
```

*The number indicates the amount of times that travel type has been seen*

This is as far as I've got, mapping the string into a initial hashmap like this:

```
(train, 1), (train, 1), (car, 1), (car, 1)...etc
```

with:

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> countTravelTypes(String travelTypes) {
    return Arrays.stream(travelTypes.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "")
            .split(","))
            .map(s -> new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{put(s, 1);}})
            //The line below isn't right but it's as close as I could get
            .reduce(0, map -> map.key, Integer.sum(v))
}
```

Can you help me with the reduction of it now, so basically summing up all the trains to show there were 4

Comment: There are just 2 trains in your source right?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala apologies it may have been misleading, I've added ellipsis to show the string isn't the full length real string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Collectors.summingInt()` for an output Map of type `Map<String, Integer>` :

```
Map<String, Integer> result =  
Stream.of("train, Train, bike, BIKE, car, BIKE, Train".split(", "))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1)));
```

Comment: Perfect! This solves the problem that the other answer had of returning a Long. Just confused what the "->1" bit inside summingInt() is doing?

Comment: Stream.of("train, Train, bike, BIKE, car, BIKE, Train".split(", "))
          .map(i->i.toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1))); Adding map to convert into Uppercase so Train, train are grouped into same element.

Comment: @Wayneio counts the occurrence of every element, that is for every element of type distinct `String` "1" (as it expects a `IntFunction`) is added to the count in the downstream collector.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `groupingBy` collector in concert with the `counting` downstream collector to get this thing done. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<String, Long> result = Arrays.stream(source.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```